# I have no sound after a Windows 10 Update

Tags: windows-10, audio, system-sounds

I have absolutely no sound from anything on my Toshiba Laptop.  Not just WMP, but even Windows system sounds, etc.

I'm running Windows 10, x64 and really need the sounds.  My drivers are all up to date.

Comment: we would need a lot more information.  what computer/sound card do you have?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it has to do with my external speakers.  My sound drivers are all up to date and the internal speakers are working.  I think that I just need to troubleshoot the externals.  I realized they're not powering on.. thanks for everyone who took a shot at answering this, it was just a user being stupid..

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your sound drivers. There should be a driver's page on Toshiba's website for drivers specific to your model. You could also try going into device manager and checking for detected sound devices. Please update your answer with more information and possible a screenshot of device manager.